# What does (myFile >> a) do?

Tags: c++, file, input, fstream

I've been learning about input from files, and I found this code snippet on stack exchange

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
std::fstream myfile("D:\\data.txt", std::ios_base::in);

float a;
while (myfile >> a)
{
    printf("%f ", a);
}

getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Other places i've looked said to use a char counter, and when char == `eof` thats when the loop stops.

What is `while (myfile >> a)` doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Answers the question wonderfully. How did you both find that so quickly? Had you seen it before and just knew to reference it?

Comment: It comes up often on here, people post code that loops with the eof test and wonder why it breaks at the end

Comment: Have linked the questions since you indicated that this answers your question